# Disabling data infile breaks MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, file-io

I run a MySQL server off my computer and have been playing around with it and PHP to access stored data. I find it works a lot better than Excel and is more cross platform/portable with export to HTML tables.

I recently was reading on how to secure MySQL and came across this article:

http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips

which has a section suggesting to disable the data infile in the mysql.conf file using:

```
set-variable=local-infile=0
```

However, after doing this, I was unable to get MySQLD to start at all. I had to remove this line to get SQL running again. Using MySQL 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2 (Ubuntu)

Anyone know another way to patch this vulnerability without breaking MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/program-variables.html says:

> Before MySQL 4.0.2, the only syntax for setting program variables was --set-variable=option=value (or set-variable=option=value in option files). ... This syntax still is recognized, but is now deprecated and is removed in MySQL 5.5.

In other words, in MySQL 5.5 and later, don't use `set-variable`. Just set the variable:

```
local-infile=0
```